# send the value as string when selecting the option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-select

I am using react-select for autocomplete and option related field. When i select the option it passes whole that option object as `{value: 'abc', label: 'ABC'}` but i wanted only to pass the value as a string not the object. Thus, i used getOptionValue but it is not working as expected.

This is what I have done

```
<Field
  name='status'
  component={SearchableText}
  placeholder="Search..."
  options={status}
  styles={styles}
  getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
  getOptionValue={option => option.value}
/>
```

I have used both `getOptionLabel` and `getOptionValue` but is still passing the selected option in object form instead of just the value as string.

Expected one

```
status: 'active'
```

Current behavior

```
status: { value: 'active', label: 'Active'}
```

Comment: Please create demo to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find `getOptionValue` in the docs for react-select, but you could always create an adapter around react-select. i.e. create your own Select component that uses react-select's Select component internally. After doing this it becomes possible to create your own `getOptionValue`. You can use this to make sure the value is a string.

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

class MySelect extends React.Component {
  getSelectValue() {
    return this.props.options.find(
      option => this.props.getOptionValue(option) === this.props.input.value
    );
  }

  render() {
    console.log("value", this.props.input.value);
    return (
      <Select
        value={this.getSelectValue()}
        onChange={option => {
          this.props.input.onChange(this.props.getOptionValue(option));
        }}
        options={this.props.options}
      />
    );
  }
}

MySelect.defaultProps = {
  getOptionValue: v => v
};

const MyForm = reduxForm({ form: "MyForm" })(
  class extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
      return (
        <Field
          name="myCoolSelect"
          component={MySelect}
          options={[
            { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
            { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
            { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
          ]}
          getOptionValue={option => option.value}
        />
      );
    }
  }
);
```

The above is a basic example of how to get this working. You may want to pass other input or meta props to take advantage of other redux-form features. e.g. `onBlur`, `onFocus`, etc. You can see it in action here: https://codesandbox.io/s/6wykjnv32n

Comment: The main problem with this code is for some select field i might need object and for some i need value as string

Comment: Are you working on this project with other people? That seems like it could cause confusion. IMO it would be better to be consistent. 

In either case this code could still work if you did something like add a boolean prop indicating the value type. e.g. `valueType={"string"}` vs `valueType={"object"}`. Alternatively, you could implement your own `getOptionValue` within `MySelect`

Comment: can you show me a sample based on getOptionValue to make it more generic, please? I understand the valueType concept but not getOptionValue you are refering

Comment: Sure, I updated the example code and the example link with a prop called getOptionValue that you can use to customize the representation of the value.