# How to get value as string, not object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-select

I use `react-select` inside my Redux form and I want me input filled with my `value` option, not the entire option.
Today, my form field is `{'label':'text', 'value':'a'}`. What I want is just `a`.

Here is my code:

```
[...]
renderField = data => {    
  return (
    <Select
      id={`xxx_${data.name}`}
      name={data.name}
      options={data.options}
      value={data.input.value}
      getOptionValue={option => option['value']}
      onChange={(value) => data.input.onChange(value)}
      onBlurResetsInput={false}
    />
  );
};

[...]
render() {
  return (
   <Field
     type={"select"}
     component={this.renderField}
     options={[{"label":"test1", "value":"a"}, {"label":"test2", "value":"b"}, {"label":"test3", "value":"c"}]}
     name={"xxx"}
   />
  );
};
```

So, I don't want the entire option in my form, but only the `value` of the option.
Do you know how to do that?

Thank you

EDIT

I tried to add a `normalize` on my field:

```
normalize={(value) => value.value}
```

It work but now, the display is wrong...

Comment: I can't say I understand why your code needs to do what it's doing here... why are you passing a component-building function to `<Field>` instead of building that `<Select>` as a normal child component?

Comment: `react-select` works on object only, why you need only value? If you need only value then why can't you use normal select?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did not put it here, but I use a component because I do other things around.

Comment: @ravibagul91 Just because I use it everywhere...

Comment: In react-select the visible value is `label`.

Comment: @user3013440 it sounds like you didn't understand my comment: why are you using `<Field component={somefunction} ... />` instead of `<Field ...>{ this.renderSelectComponent(...) }</Field>`? That `Field` should not need to know anything about what its content is, and it should certainly not be "half aware": you're passing it options, which only make sense for a Select, but then you also pass it a pure mystery function which might render something _completely different_ so this is not a very good pattern to use.

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067985/send-the-value-as-string-when-selecting-the-option ?